# Build a Makefile command by iterating in a loop

Tags: loops, makefile

I want to "build" a command directly into my Makefile.
I would need something like this:

```
# Makefile

CLUSTERS: 1 2 3

build:
COMMAND=""
for cluster in $(CLUSTERS) ; do \
    COMMAND+=$(shell echo "path\to\command command "$$cluster" & ") ; \
done
COMMAND+=$(shell echo "wait")
$(DOCKER_EXEC) ${COMMAND}
```

Then, `make build` would be equivalent to:

```
path\to\command command 1 & path\to\command command 2 & path\to\command command 3 & wait
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you use GNU `Makefile`.

In this case

```
CLUSTERS=1 2 3                       
COMMAND=$(subst &, &,$(addprefix path\to\command command,$(addsuffix &,${CLUSTERS}))   
COMMAND+="wait"

build:
    $(DOCKER_EXEC) ${COMMAND}
```

Comment: I updated my question,  it wasn't clear enough (sorry). I need to be able to send the entire command inside a docker container.

Comment: With:
`$(addprefix $(addprefix path/to/command ,command) ,$(addsuffix &, ${CLUSTERS} ))`

I got
`path/to/command command 1& path/to/command command 2& path/to/command command 3&`

It's pretty close but I need a space between **figures** and **&** like:
`path/to/command command 1 & path/to/command command  2 & path/to/command command 3 &`

Comment: @RaDyUm I hope it's perfect now :)